# How can I import event to external calendar in android mobile device with rails?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, events, import, icalendar

I have got a problem with importing event to external calendar in android mobile device. ICS format is not available on my phone. I have got a solution only for samsung devices and devices using IOS. Have anybody got an idea how to resolve my problem?

My solution:

```
@event = Event.find(params[:id])
    cal = Icalendar::Calendar.new
    # filename = "Event #{@event.name}"
    filename = @event.name

    if params[:format] == 'vcs'
      cal.prodid = '-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook MIMEDIR//EN'
      cal.version = '1.0'
      filename += '.vcs'
    else # ical
      cal.prodid = '-//Acme Widgets, Inc.//NONSGML ExportToCalendar//EN'
      cal.version = '2.0'
      filename += '.ics'
    end

    cal.event do |e|
      e.dtstart     = Icalendar::Values::DateTime.new(@event.start_date)
      e.dtend       = Icalendar::Values::DateTime.new(@event.end_date)
      e.summary     = @event.name
      e.description = @event.description
    end
    # text/x-vCalendar
    send_data cal.to_ical, type: 'text/calendar', disposition: 'attachment', filename: filename
```